# Percentile MSExcel query

Tags: excel, data-mining

Is it possible to find percentile of a) a column called "Country" with text based column values

b) a column called "Salary" with column values either of the following - <=50K, >50K

Answer (score 0):

Would something along the lines of the below work?

```
=Countif(A1:A999,<=50000)/count(A1:A999)
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS for the country based text column the same way as above.